# Convert gridview row values to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

If i have grid view that has the following data

```
TechnicianID FirstName LastName

1            yasser    jon

2            ali       kamal
```

How can convert these grid row values into string in this below format

```
yasser jon , ali kamal
```

GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridtechnicians" CssClass="hidden" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TechnicianID" HeaderText="TechnicianID" SortExpression="TechnicianID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Do they have common id?

Comment: each technician has different id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Foreach` loop on rows in your `DataGridView` and get values. This sample show how you can resolve your problem.

```
 string yourString = String.Empty;

 foreach (GridViewRow rowDatos in this.gridtechnicians.Rows)
    {
      if (rowDatos.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
      string firstName=gridtechnicians.DataKeys[rowDatos.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
      string lastName=gridtechnicians.DataKeys[rowDatos.RowIndex].Values[2].ToString();  

      yourString += firstName+" "+lastName  
      }
    }
```

Comment: I guess, this is implemented inside the `GridView` RowDataBound event.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `Label` like that :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName") %>' />
```